# Output not matching the expected output for almost palindrome program in C++

Tags: c++, function, call

I can't find any error in my code for an almost palindrome. The statement

'r = isPalindrome(str, p[0], p[1]-1);'

is not getting executed while the function calls for p&q are getting executed fine. It prints values of only p & q. Can someone please explain what is wrong with the flow of the program?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int arr[2];


int* isPalindrome(string &s, int i, int j){

    int sz = s.length();

    if(i==j) return NULL;

    while(i<j){

        if(s[i] == s[j]){
            i++;
            j--;
        }

        else{
            arr[0] = i;
            arr[1] = j;
            return arr;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}


int main()
{

   string s = "abcdefdba", str;
   int *p, *q, *r;

   // removes any additional character or spaces and make lower-case
   for(int i=0; i<s.length();i++){
    if(s[i] >= 65 && s[i]<=90) str.push_back(s[i]+32);
    if((s[i] >=97 && s[i]<=122) || (s[i]>=48 && s[i]<=57)) str.push_back(s[i]);
   }

    p = isPalindrome(str, 0, str.length()-1);

    cout<<"pointer p: "<<p[0]<<p[1]<<endl;

    if(p==NULL) cout<<"true";

    else{
         q = isPalindrome(str, p[0]+1, p[1]);

         r = isPalindrome(str, p[0], p[1]-1); // not getting executed
        }


    cout<<"pointer q: "<<q[0]<<q[1]<<endl;
    cout<<"pointer r: "<<r[0]<<r[1]<<endl;

    if(q==NULL || r==NULL) cout<<"true";
    else cout<<"false";


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: where do you check if `isPalindrome` returns `NULL` ? Why does it not return `bool` ?

Comment: I'm not returning bool because I need the position of non-matching characters so I can remove them and check if the rest is a palindrome.

P is checking for null i.e the string is already a palindrome
q,r checking for null to know if the substring after removing character is a palindrome

Comment: is no output the only evidence you have that the function is not called? Because thats a rather farfetched conclusion. If either `p` or `q` are `NULL` passing them to `std::cout <<` invokes UB and anything could happen

Comment: @Mohan Same here, how do you know it is not executed?

Comment: if the whole string is a palindrome then removing first or last character is not a palindrom (unless some trivial cases)

Comment: @Mohan You are deferencing a NULL pointer so that means your code is bugged.

Comment: In the debug, it was showing 0x0 for r

Comment: "In the debug, it was showing 0x0 for r" then why do you expect to get something meaningful from printing `r[0]` or `r[1]` ?

Comment: @Mohan That does not prove the function was not called. Only that it returned NULL.

Comment: @Mohan Your code has a few bugs, centered around the return of a pointer to a global array (and also the return of NULL).

Comment: @Mohan Since you are using a debugger, try stepping into the function, and see for sure whether it is being called.

Comment: you should edit the question and include output and expected output, because your interpretation is not sound. Actually it might be that the function isnt called because the compiler has all information available to see that your code has undefined behavior, and anything can happen in the presence of UB, but so far there is no evidence that the function is not called

Comment: @Mohan Here's what seems to be the biggest bug. Your code writes the return values to a global array. After the 1st call to the function `p` points to that global array. Then you call the function for a 2nd time, **this writes new values to the global array**. However you still use that `p` pointer. I'm guessing that you expected `p` to still be pointing at the return values from the 1st call to your function. But it isn't, those values have been changed by the 2nd call to your function. The moral is, don't use global variables.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what UB means. The compiler shows no errors/warnings. I'll try to debug again if the function is being called actually or is it an error due to returning NULL pointer

Comment: Those `if` statements inside the `for` loop should just be `if (std::isalnum(s[I]) str.push_back(std::tolower(s[I])`. Or maybe `tolower` should be `toupper`; I don't remember which way ASCII goes, and I don't care to. The standard library takes care of all that.

Comment: @PeteBecker wrote this so it can also take care of any spaces or , : along with lower/ upper case "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"

Comment: @Mohan -- I understand why the code is there. I suggested a better way to write it.

Comment: @john Thanks! I understood. The function call q changes the values of arr to 4,5 and p is still pointing to this global variable so instead of calling r with 2,5, it is calling with 4,4 which is why getting NULL. 

The lesson is to use local variables instead in functions.

Comment: @Mohan Great, except don't return pointers to local variables, that's even worse because you end up with a pointer to a variable which has been destroyed. In your function you effectively want to return three values, true/false and if true then two character positions. I think the simplest approach would be to change your function to return a bool, and add two *reference* parameters for the positions. No pointers needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you are right and the function isn't execute and lets find out why the compiler might optimize it in such a way that the function call is not needed:

`int* isPalindrome(string &s, int i, int j)` returns a pointer to the global array `arr` or NULL and other than writing to arr it has no side effect.

Lets analyze the main function then:

```
p = isPalindrome(str, 0, str.length()-1);

cout<<"pointer p: "<<p[0]<<p[1]<<endl;

if(p==NULL) cout<<"true";
else {
```

You dereferrence `p` so `p` must not be NULL, the compiler can always take the else branch.

```
     q = isPalindrome(str, p[0]+1, p[1]);

     r = isPalindrome(str, p[0], p[1]-1); // not getting executed
    }


cout<<"pointer q: "<<q[0]<<q[1]<<endl;
cout<<"pointer r: "<<r[0]<<r[1]<<endl;

if(q==NULL || r==NULL) cout<<"true";
else cout<<"false";
```

Again you dereferrence `q` and `r` so they can not be NULL. So isPalindrom must have returned the address of `arr` in both cases and  must have written `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`, which is `p`, `q` and `r`. The second `isPalindrom` call changes `p[0]` and `p[1]` and that changes what the thrid `isPalindrom` call does. I don't think any of them can be skipped.

But the compiler can potentially compute it all at compile time and eliminate it all.

In the output you should see that the last two `cout` calls print the same thing. Maybe that makes you think one of the function calls is skipped. But what you see is that they both just print the same global `arr`.

---

What you should do is return `std::optional<std::pair<int, int>>` instead of the global array.

Better: `int` is not the right type of an index, that should be `std::size_t`. So `std::optional<std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>>`

Why not return iterators of the substring instead? And make it const, the argument should be a `const std::string &`: `std::optional<std::pair<std::string::const_iterator, std::string::const_iterator>>`

Or lets get really modern and return a string view: `std::optional<std::string_view>`